# Fastest way to get access to the following value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I seem to have some difficulty understanding the way these jQuery selectors work.

Say you have this sort of html

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="something" value="1" class="class_name" />

    <div>
        <input class="blur_function" name="email" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And the following jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.blur_function').live('blur',function(){

       // get the value of the hidden input above 
       var something = $(this).prev('.class_name').val();

   });

});
```

I would imagine this 'prev('.class_name') would traverse upwards in the code until it hits something with class="class_name", however I end up with *undefined* since it traverses only within the element its inside.

So I need to do something like this to get outside the parent div and within the scope of the previous .class_name:

```
  var something = $(this).parent().prev('.class_name').val();
```

Is there a faster way to do this using the same html structure?

Comment: why not just $('.class_name').val()

Comment: there might be multiple .class_name's on the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest:

```
var something = $('.class_name', $(this).closest('form')).val();
```

to select all the inputs that are direct children:

```
var something = $('> .class_name', $(this).closest('form')).val();
```

to select only the first `.class_name` that is direct child of the form:

```
var something = $('> .class_name:first', $(this).closest('form')).val();
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ueZcU/)

Comment: thats fancy. i don't know why it works though.. isn't that comma in the selector supposed to make it select 2 objects??

Comment: @cosmicbdog actually the comma is after the selector, passing 2 param to the jQuery function

Comment: Which means that it's looking for `'.class_name'` within the *scope* of `$(this).closest('form')`. Another example which might help explain is: the following two are the same `$('#example .class_name')` and `$('.class_name', '#example')`

Comment: interesting! I had no idea you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your use case is not a particularly common one.  In many cases, what you really want can be defined within the ancestor/descendant framework.  I suspect your actual use case meets this criteria as well.

It's a matter of happenstance that your `.class_name` element happens to be a sibling of an ancestor.  If your HTML changes slightly for layout purposes, this may no longer be the case. What *is* important is that your `.class_name` element shares the same ancestor `form` as the `.blur_function`.

Given that, here's my suggestion:

```
$('.blur_function')
  .closest('form')
    .find('.class_name')
      .val()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Why not select it based on its name?

`var someValue = $('input[name="something"]').val();`

Comment: That would be ideal (selecting it directly) however there might be multiple forms and input[name="something"]'s.